# Validity of pointwise estimate involving spatial derivative of Sobolev function

Tags: derivatives, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

We consider a Sobolev function $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some $p>1$ and a bounded domain $\Omega\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Assuming we have shown the inequality
$$|\partial_s u(x)|=|\nabla u(x) \cdot s|\leq C$$
for a.e. $x\in B_R\Subset \Omega$ and any $s\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $|s|=1$, where $C>0$ denotes some finite quantity (so we have a pointwise estimate for the directional derivative of $u$ in direction $s$). Does this in particular imply
$$|\nabla u(x)|\leq C  \quad (*)$$
for a.e. $x\in B_R\Subset \Omega$? I know that the choice $\hat{s}=\frac{\nabla u(x)}{|\nabla u(x)|}$ ($|\hat{s}|=1$) would yield that - however, with this choice $\hat{s}$ would depend on the spatial point $x$, and in the inequality above I think of the spatial direction $s$ as constant, i.e. s should be independent of $x$. So my question is: does this dependence on $x$ not pose an issue in the choice of $\hat{s}$ or is there another way to see the validity of $(*)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ is independent of $s$, then the claim follows: it is a consequence of the equivalence:
$$
\|x\|_2 \le c \ \Leftrightarrow  |x^Ts|\le c \quad\forall s: \|s\|_2\le 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This equivalence probably already holds true by weaking the assumption to $\forall s$: $|s|=1$, right? Edit: Yes ok that is straightforward to see.

Comment: Since I asked a question concerning this problem in another post but unfortunately did not receive a response yet, I will try my luck here. After thinking about this for a while, I am unsure whether the expression $\partial_s u$, which denotes the \textbf{weak} directional derivative, actually makes sense. I would interpret it as the scalarproduct of the weak gradient (which exists per definition) with the vector $s$, which is a.e. defined. However, I couldn't found the expression "weak directional derivative" anywhere. Do you maybe know, if this actually makes sense?

Comment: I would expect that one can define a weak directional derivative by integration-by-parts similarly to the weak derivative. Also there are mixed/anisotropic Sobolev spaces of functions, where not all partial derivative up to an given order need to exist.